# Jest encountered an unexpected token - import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill' breaks test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

My Jest tests break when I add this to my code:

`import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill';`

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html
```

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "fas-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.5.3",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "connected-react-router": "^4.4.1",
    "formik": "^1.1.1",
    "hello.js": "^1.0.0",
    "hellojs": "^2.0.0-4",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.8.0",
    "loadjs": "^3.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "promise-polyfill": "8.1.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-bs-notifier": "^5.0.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^1.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.0.1",
    "react-ga": "^2.5.6",
    "react-google-oauth": "^1.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.1",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.9.0",
    "recharts": "^1.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "yup": "^0.26.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^23.6.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I've tried setting the config stuff documented here:

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string

I can't figure out which file to add it to or how to set this up.  All this polyfill does is provide IE support, so I don't need it (or could mock it) for Jest, I just can't figure out how to make Jest mock this for the tests.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your creating a React-Redux App and using just with Enzyme to test this.

If you're creating a single page application it's best practice to have an index page that sets up the environment and will render your App component.

If you set up your environment here (such as the promise-polyfill) you can guarantee it will be present through the rest of your project.

You will also render the App with something like:

```
ReactDOM.Render(App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

The Index  part of the process however shouldn't regularly be tested. For one you would have to add an element to jsdom with the id of 'root'.

Instead you should be testing the App component itself which shouldn't be importing the index page.